# How do I access data from my web.config file from my user controls?

Tags: asp.net

How do I access data from my web.config file from my user controls (.ascx)?

Comment: so you need your code-behind to read from your web.config?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ConfigurationManager class. If it's not available, add Configuration assembly to your project.